# how can I record the touching trail (x and y coordinations) when I touch and move on screen of the phone?

Tags: javascript, ionic2, touchmove

I'm using the ionic2 to programing a mobile app.I want to record the whole trail when the finger touch and move on the screeen.first,I used the

```html
 document.addEventListener('touchmove',touch,false);
```

but when the finger touch and move on the screen,the app only fire the touchmove event one time, I can only get a point, 
not a series of touched points,how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup event bindings for **touchstart** and **touchmove**. These event bindings will call the method when screen will be **touched** or **dragged** and return trail of coordinates.

> **home.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div 
    id="my-div"
    (touchstart)="handlestart($event)"
    (touchmove)="handlemove($event)">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

> **home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {
  handlestart(event) {
    console.log('start: X:' + event.touches[0].pageX + ', Y:' +event.touches[0].pageY);
  }

  handlemove(event) {
    console.log('move: X:' + event.touches[0].pageX + ', Y:' +event.touches[0].pageY);
  }
}
```

> **Output**

[image]